# How to activate jumping link and link to iframe with a single anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to implement the following functionality. When the user click on the thumbnail/link, the image of that thumbnail will be displayed on the iframe, at the same time jumping to the description of that thumbnail - Thank You

```
    <style>
        .flex-container{
            display: flex;
        }
        .scrollBox{
            overflow: auto;
            width: 400px;
            height: 530px;
        }
    </style>

<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <nav class="navigation">
            <a href="../img/image1.png" target="full-size">
                image1
            </a>
            <br>
            <a href="../img/image2" target="full-size">
                image2
            </a>
        </nav>
        <iframe name="full-size" width="245" height="560" 
                src="../img/image1">
        </iframe>
        <div class="scrollBox">
            <h1>Image1 Descriptions</h1[![enter image description here][1]][1]>
            Lorem120
            <hr>
            <h2>Image2 Descriptions</h2>
            Lorem200
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image: Example]

My Attempt:
When I clicked on the thumbnail, it'll also click on another anchor tag that'll jump to the description (I just hide the tag that link to the description).

```
    <script>
        function jumpToDescription(){
            document.getElementsByTagName("a")[2].click();
        }
    </script>
      <div class="flex-container">
            <a href="../img/image1.png" target="full-size" onclick="jumpToDescription()">
                image1
            </a>
            .
            .
            .
            <a style="display: none" href="#image1Description">Image1</a>
    </div>
```

My question is how can I rewrite `jumpToDescription()` to make the function reusable? Instead of creating a unique function for every thumbnail with a unique .getElementsByTagName's index number. Also if you guys have a better approach than this one I'm open to it as well. - Thank You

Comment: You really should show what you have attempted to do so far, how did you try to achieve the desired functionality. Hint: JS.

Comment: Sorry about that let me re-Edit the question. I just didn't think my attempt was the best approach but here's what I tried so far